# how to fix 'MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h' file not found error in winobjc

Tags: winobjc

I want to port my ios app to windows desktop app using winobjc.
I imported my xcode project using vsimporter.exe, and tried to build it.
But it displays error" 'MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h' file not found".
How to fix it?

Comment: can you show any code to talk about? Thank you! See the [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section